# Drag and Drop to a Sprite in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, drag-and-drop, flex4

I need to detect when a user d-b-n-d an object into a sprite. I'm adding the 3 event listeners I need, but only one of them works:

`ontainer.addEventListener( DragEvent.DRAG_ENTER, dragEnterHandler);
container.addEventListener( DragEvent.DRAG_EXIT, dragExitHandler);
container.addEventListener( DragEvent.DRAG_DROP, dragDropHandler);`

The only one I can listen to is DRAG_ENTER. And I'm using to accept the dragged object:

DragManager.acceptDragDrop(event.currentTarget.parent as IUIComponent);

Any ideas why I can't listen to the other two events?

tks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_5.html#174367)...

> To accept the drop, the event handler calls the DragManager.acceptDragDrop() method. You must call the DragManager.acceptDragDrop() method for the drop target to receive the dragOver, dragExit, and dragDrop events.

Comment: I'm already doing that, "acceptDragDrop", and the drag is accepted, but once I release the mouse button, the DragEvent.DRAG_DROP is not dispatched.